# Combinations of given number that add up to X

Tags: c, combinations

Though it shouldn't be really difficult, I've been kind of stuck with this. I need to make a function in C, that computes and shows all the possible combinations (without repetition) of given number, where the digits (that only range from 1 to 9) of every combination give a specified sum when added.

I guess it's not the clearest explanation, so here is an example: Calculate all sets of 5 numbers (from 1 to 9) that add up to 28.

I would be really grateful, if someone could explain this.

Comment: Since there are only `512` different choices, you could precompute the results easily.-

Comment: @giorashc I was thinking of calculating all the possibilities, and then discarding the ones that don't add up to the given sum, but I guess it's not very efficient. In any case, I haven't yet thought of a way of calculating those, combinatorics is not really my forte

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Could you be more specific please?

Comment: You're kind of asking everything at once rather than a specific question. Can you focus the question very specifically on precisely where you get stuck? Otherwise, if we tell you a method of doing it, because it's not the method that makes the most sense for you, it will be much harder for you to understand it.

Comment: 1. Does the user input the quantify of numbers? 2. You said that you can't repeat combinations (I think {1,3} and {3,1}) but what about numbers can you repeat them {3,3} ? 3. Is there any max quantify of numbers for the combinations? 4. What have you tried until now?

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only 512 different choices, you could precompute the results easily.

To precompute:

- Prepare an empty map(sum => set(set(digit))), named `lookup`.
- for every `subset` of (1..9)

  - compute its `sum`.
  - If `lookup` does not have the key `sum`, create a new entry, an empty set.
  - add the `subset` to `lookup[sum]`

To lookup a `sum`:

- if `lookup` has the key `sum`, return (a copy of) the entry. Else return an empty set.

---

To address some of the low-level-ness of C:

A map int=>x is simply an array. A set of x is simply an array + length too.

The array for the map can be allocated as static since you already know the largest key, 45.

You can pre-estimate the largest set of sets as well, or use dynamic allocation (more efficient). If you don't care about space, you can easily over-allocate (512 entries max.).  I presume you don't want to over-allocate this much, so you could as well learn how to allocate dynamically.

A set of digits can be represented as a 9-bit bit mask (16 bits in memory). Then they're easy to enumerate.

A sketch of the actual type for `lookup`:

```
typedef setOfDigits int16;

struct setOfSets{
  setOfDigits* data;
  int16 count; //the actual amount of sets in the set
  int16 space; //the size of the allocated array
}

setOfSets lookup[46];
```

A sketch of the actual type for `lookup`, without dynamic allocation or `struct`s:

```
int16 lookup[46][512];
int16 lookupLength[46];
```

Note that if you equate `space:=count`, then you never over-allocate, but you often re-allocate, which is easier to implement but potentially inefficient (but the code's run once, so hey)

Of course, high-level languages (and even C++) have dynamic arrays either natively (javascript) or through a standard library (C++, Java). In C, you have to rely on `realloc`.

Comment: Too complex for him, I bet he doesn't know what a structure or a pointer is. But +1 for the explanation.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto too bad you need to know pointers if you do dynamic allocation (and a struct is really helpful here).